# How to combine repositories while retaining the directory structure?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have many projects that "fit together". They share source files.

[image]

Each project (including tens of tests) has its own Mercurial repository.

I would like to join all these repositories into a master repository and **retain the same directory structure.**

```
mkdir MasterProject
cd MasterProject
mkdir "Common_sources"
hg init
hg pull ../Common_sources Common_sources
```

The last statement obviously doesn't work that way, but it is **exactly** the behaviour that I would like. That is, copy all the files and their histories and place them into the `Common_sources` directory.

How can I achieve this in Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) to do this.

What you need to do is to convert the source repositories using a filemap to move all the files in the repository into a sub-folder.  To do this for the **Common_sources** folder you would use this command:

```
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt Common_sources Common_sources.tmp
```

The **filemap.txt** file would contain this line of text:

```
rename . Common_sources
```

After the convert, you have a repository called **Common_sources.tmp** with the same history as **Common_sources** except for the fact that all the files are in a sub-directory.

You would perform a similar task on all the repositories that you want to combine and then combine them into one project as follows:

```
mkdir MasterProject
hg init
hg pull ../Common_sources.tmp
hg pull ../Integration_tests -f
hg merge
hg commit -m "Merging integration tests"
```

Repeating the pull, merge and commit for each project that you want to add into the repository project.

When that's all done you can finish off with an `hg update` to see all the new folders in the master repository.